# Como estruturar o desenvolvimento de um programa?

Tags: projeto-de-software, gerenciamento-de-projetos, organização-de-projeto

Estou prestes a dar início no software que eu vou desenvolver para o TCC (C# + MySQL). O problema (por enquanto) não é código, e sim como eu vou desenvolver meu projeto de maneira estruturada, e sem me "enrolar" muito durante o desenvolvimento do mesmo. Eu elaborei um exercício para praticar, mas gostaria de aplicar um *checklist* (ou passo a passo) em sequência que garante um bom desenvolvimento (diagramas, criação do BD, estruturar o BD, integração BD + software, interface gráfica.

Situação problema, que eu criei com o proposito de treinar:

Projeto que gerencia clientes e contas

1. poderemos cadastrar clientes e contas, mas cada conta será
   associada para um cliente
2. cada cliente pode ter varias contas, e
       as contas poderão ser visualizadas em lista.
3. poderemos fazer
           transferência, depósitos e retiradas de dinheiro das contas.
4. Caso o  valor da
       transferência for menor que o saldo, devemos impedir a transação